# MySQL views and math between current and previous row

Tags: php, mysql

I am collecting data from a solar charge controller into a MySQL database (5.5.52). So far I have a TABLE, *registers*:

```
mysql> SELECT date,time,panelVoltage,panelCurrent,batteryVoltage,loadCurrent
  FROM registers
  ORDER BY date,time
  LIMIT 4;
+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| date       | time     | panelVoltage | panelCurrent | batteryVoltage | loadCurrent |
+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2016-11-27 | 17:20:41 |        26.04 |         1.31 |          25.15 |        0.72 |
| 2016-11-27 | 17:21:06 |        26.06 |         1.31 |          25.15 |        0.76 |
| 2016-11-27 | 17:21:32 |        26.06 |         1.15 |          25.16 |         0.6 |
| 2016-11-27 | 17:21:57 |        26.06 |          1.3 |          25.16 |        0.68 |
+------------+----------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+
```

I would like to calculate Watt hours for the panel and load as a VIEW I suppose, so it keeps up to date. The (very) pseudocode:

```
SELECT (panelVoltage * panelCurrent) as panelWattage,
  CONCAT(date, ' ', time) AS datetime
  FROM registers ORDER BY datetime;
timeDiff = (currRow.datetime from prevRow.datetime)/3600 # for time decimal hours
powerSum = (currRow.panelWattage + prevRow.panelWattage)/2 # for average Wattage
Wh = timeDiff * powerSum # for Watt-hours
```

So the view/columns would hold `panelWh` and `loadWh` and maybe a running sum of each, `panelWhSum`, `loadWhSum`.

Here is my php code doing just that - I understand a view would be way more efficient:

```
  $qry = "SELECT CONCAT(date,' ',time) as datetime,loadCurrent,batteryVoltage,panelCurrent,panelVoltage,
    panelCurrent * panelVoltage as 'panelWatt', loadCurrent * batteryVoltage as 'loadWatt' FROM registers
    WHERE TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`) > NOW() - INTERVAL ".$_GET['time']." MINUTE";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'datetime', 'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'panel Wh', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'load Wh', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'net Wh', 'type' => 'number')
  foreach($result as $row){
    $prevTime = $curTime;
    $curTime = $datetime;
    $prevPW = $curPW;
    $curPW = $row['panelWatt'];
    $prevLW = $curLW;
    $curLW = $row['loadWatt'];
    if ($i == 0) {
      $prevTime = $datetime;
      $prePW = $row['panelWatt'];
      $preLW = $row['loadWatt'];
    }
    $diffInSeconds = $curTime->getTimestamp() - $prevTime->getTimestamp();
    $panelWh = ($diffInSeconds * 0.5 * ($prevPW + $curPW) / 3600);
    $panelWhTotal = $panelWhTotal + $panelWh;
    $loadWh = ($diffInSeconds * 0.5 * ($prevLW + $curLW) / 3600);
    $loadWhTotal = $loadWhTotal + $loadWh;
    $temp[] = array('v' => (float) round($panelWhTotal, 2));
    $temp[] = array('v' => (float) round($loadWhTotal, 2));
    $temp[] = array('v' => (float) round(($panelWhTotal - $loadWhTotal), 2));
  }
```

graphed examples from the above PHP code:
[panel, load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9WKr.png)
[Watt-hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnAXe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you with a table like the following. See that i have seperate data and time columns.It help me to do a graph something like that you want
[image]

[image]

Comment: And how do you calculate visitor hours in SQL? I.E. how much was the resource used in visitor-hours, the area under your curve?

Comment: I set the 24 day hours in this array

Comment: a=["00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00",               "11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00",
                "19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"];

Comment: And the i count the visitors from eg 14:00 until 14:59 with this sql query  $query="SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE visitor_day=$present_day AND visitor_hour=$i AND visitor_minute<=59

Comment: And the i count the visitors from eg 14:00 until 14:59 with this sql query  $query="SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE visitor_day=$present_day AND visitor_hour=$i AND visitor_minute<=59. You can use an another query with semi hour interval eg   $query="SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE visitor_day=$present_day AND visitor_hour=$i AND visitor_minute<=29

Comment: I don't follow - where is the math subtracting one absolute time from another to get a dT and where is the equation multiplying the average visitors at each of those absolute times by dT?

Comment: This: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/electric/watt-to-wh.htm or this http://smallbusiness.chron.com/calculate-man-hours-2933.html The SQL code you offer only tells me how many vistors at a singular time. I'd like to know how many visitor*hours are spent on the site.

Comment: You can sum all the visitors (or watts) on the specific day and get the sum

Comment: A sum of the Watts/Visitors is not the same as usage/the area under the curves of either graph. The formula for usage is (Time2-Time1)*(VisitorsAtTime1 + VisitorsAtTime2)/2

Comment: In your example sum(visitors) = 16
visitorHours = well, not sure, there is no duration information on how long a particular visitor browsed, their particular Visitor*hour value.

Comment: I don't use code to see how much a visitor stay in my site.I am interesting to count the visit.If i want the duration the i must use session cookie (it is an another procession);

Comment: We are doing different things and interested in different data and the two are not compatible (visitors/hour not equivalent to Wh). I appreciate your input.